# How to cancel SemaphoreSlim WaitAsync method

Tags: c#, .net-5, cancellationtokensource

Consider the following code, executed with `.NET 5`:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0);

        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var entrance = semaphore.WaitAsync(cts.Token);

        cts.Cancel();
        cts.Dispose();

        semaphore.Release();

        Console.WriteLine("Entrance status: " + entrance.Status);
        Console.WriteLine("Current count: " + semaphore.CurrentCount);
    }
}
```

When I run this code, the application complete successfully and I got the following result:

> Entrance status: WaitingForActivation
>
> Current count: 0

But since I cancel the `WaitAsync` operation before releasing the semaphore, I was expecting the semaphore `CurrentCount` to be `1` and the `Task` to be in the `Canceled` status.

Before posting the question, I ran the code within https://dotnetfiddle.net and surprisingly, it ran as I expected with the `.NET Framework 4.7.2`.

Do I find a bug in .NET 5 `SemaphoreSlim`?

Is there a way to get the former behavior in `.NET 5`?

PS: I find a way to get the former behavior by setting a timeout to the `WaitAsync` operation, but that's not an acceptable answer to my opinion.

**EDIT according to Guru Stron comments**

Awaiting `entrance` before the `Release` statement produces an `OperationCancelledException` as I would expect.

But awaiting after the statement does not throw any exception and the semaphore is "consumed".

Where both cases produce an error in former `.NET Framework`.

Comment: If you add `Console.WriteLine("Entrance status: " + entrance.Status);` after the `Release`  statement it will report `Canceled` status.

Comment: Also awaiting the task will throw the expected error. And after that `Status` is also changed to expected.

Comment: @GuruStron: I changed the code so often before posting it that I made a mistake. Awaiting before the `Release` statement will produce the `OperationCancelledException` as expected, but awaiting after will successfully complete.

Comment: I would expect both cases result in `OperationCancelledException`, as it does in .NET 4.7.2.

Comment: Yes, was able to repro in .NET 6 rc also. Checking status twice makes it to needed one))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CancellationTokenSource.Cancel` is a request to cancel. The cancellation tokens become canceled immediately, but `Cancel` does *not* guarantee to wait, blocking the current thread, until all operations listening to that cancellation token have been canceled (and their parent operations, etc).

In other words, your code has an inherent race condition: whether the `Release` or the `CancellationToken`'s cancellation will reach the `WaitAsync` operation first. If the `Release` reaches it first, then the semaphore will be acquired. If the cancellation reaches it first, then the wait will be canceled.

`await`ing the `WaitAsync` operation's task before calling `Release` resolves this race condition by (a)waiting the operation, forcing it to see the cancellation before the `Release` is sent.

> Do I find a bug in .NET 5 SemaphoreSlim?

No. The code was depending on a race condition, both on .NET Framework and on .NET 5. The result of the race condition is not guaranteed to have any specific result on either platform.

> Is there a way to get the former behavior in .NET 5?

No. I recommend reworking the code so that it does not depend on a race condition. Then it will work correctly for both platforms.

It's *possible* that the code is using `SemaphoreSlim` for something it wasn't designed for. E.g., if you need a queue of asynchronous work, then build a queue of asynchronous work instead of trying to use a `SemaphoreSlim` as one.